# Finding the marginal distribution from a joint PDF - I can't find my mistake

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

The continuous random vars X and Y have the joint PDF:

f(x,y) = a($y^2 - x^2)$      $$ 0 \le  x \le y \le \theta $$

I have found the value of a by computing the definite integral, setting to 1 and solving for a. The result I got was

$$a = \frac{6}{\theta^4 - x^4} $$

This has proven a complete nightmare when trying to find the marginal distribution of Y. I have been unable to integrate $\frac{6}{\theta^4 - x^4}(y^2 - x^2)$ with respect to x, leading me to suspect my value of a is incorrect. I have repeated the integral multiple times and just cannot get a value for a that is usable in the next step.

if someone can suggest a way forward I would be very grateful.

Comment: $a$ should be a constant, and not a function of $x$ (or $y$). I think you have made a mistake in the integration. And I strongly suspect you used variable limits for the outer integral. The outer integral should always have constant limits

Answer (score 1):

Your integral should be 
$$
a = \frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\theta} \int_{x}^{\theta} (y^2 - x^2) dy dx}
$$
I get $a = \frac{\theta^4}{6}$ unless I messed up the algebra somewhere.